# How many ways of arranging pairs of shoes on a shelf

Tags: combinatorics

This seemed to me a quite trivial question, until I saw the suggested answer.

The problem is:
*Michael has 3 pairs of shoes and 4 pairs of trainers. In how many ways can he put them side-by-side on a shelf so that the pairs of each type stay together?*

To me the answer seemed trivial.

We have two big groups, the trainers and the shoes. There are $2$ ways of putting them together (Trainers,Shoes or Shoes,Trainers).

Inside the shoes group, we then have $3$ pairs of shoes we can sort in $3!$ ways.
Inside the trainers group, we have $4$ pairs of shoes we can sort in $4!$ ways.
Each of the seven pairs overall can be sorted in $2!$ by exchanging each shoe from the pair (Left,Right or Right,Left); so we should have $(2!)^7$ ways of exchanging the shoes of all pairs.

So to me, we have a total of $2 \times 3! \times 4! \times (2!)^7 = 36834 $.

Yet **the right answer seems to be $645120$**. I tried all sorts of interpretations to the problem and I never reached this number. Where am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: $645120 = 2^{11}\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 7!\cdot 2^7$.  That seems to be "pairs of each type stay together" meaning the left shoeA stays with the right shoeA but might or might not necessarily be next to shoeB or shoeC..

Comment: Their answer seems to only care that shoes within a pair are kept together (*left shoeA with right shoeA, left shoeB with right shoeB, left trainerA with right trainerA, etc...*) but do not care about *categories* of shoes staying together (*you can have shoeA then trainerA then shoeB is just fine*).  Your answer assumed that shoes of a category must all stay together as well which was more restrictive than their answer.  You answered correctly for your interpretation.  They were unclear about what they meant by "type" here.

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz . Definitely the word "type" was ambiguous here. As you said, shoes within the same pair would be way clearer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it's shoes or trainers, as the restriction for them to be in pairs already makes them into unique sets - so this is equivalent to having 7 pairs of shoes or 7 pairs of trainers. Now the only thing you need to care about is that the pairs are together. If each pair were together there would simply be $7!$ different permutations assuming each shoe in a pair was identical, but they're not. You also have two ways the shoes in each pair can be organized (left-right,right-left) and therefore you have another $2^7$ different permutations for each of the $7!$ permutations. This makes the total number of permutations:

\begin{align}
N_\text{Permutations} = 7!*2^7=645120 
\end{align}

Comment: +1 nice reverse engineering